# perl ".../config.h, needed by `Makefile'" not working after OSX Lion upgrade

Tags: perl, macos, cpan, osx-lion

**SOLVED.** See at bottom.

Just upgraded to OSX Lion and trying to get my Perl install running again:

`sudo /usr/bin/perl -MCPAN -e 'install "MODULENAME"'`

with any value of `MODULENAME` that I tried (e.g. `JSON`) produces:

```
...
Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Writing Makefile for JSON
make: *** No rule to make target `/System/Library/Perl/5.12/darwin-thread-multi-2level/CORE/config.h', needed by `Makefile'.  Stop.
  MAKAMAKA/JSON-2.53.tar.gz
  /Developer/usr/bin/make -- NOT OK
```

I can't find anything resembling `config.h` anywhere, the directory exists though ...

Not even this works:

```
/usr/bin/cpan CPAN
```

**SOLVED:** Download and install latest version of XCode from AppStore. Note that just downloading XCode from AppStore does not install it (why, Apple, oh why?) but only dumps an installer into /Applications. Run the installer, which will fix this issue.

Comment: Why `/usr/bin/perl` instead of `perl`? Isn't `/usr/bin` in your `$PATH`?

Comment: Just to be clear to everybody that I'm not invoking the wrong perl ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

SOLVED: Download and install latest version of XCode from AppStore. Note that just downloading XCode from AppStore does not install it (why, Apple, oh why?) but only dumps an installer into /Applications. Run the installer, which will fix this issue.

Comment: Thanks a lot for documenting the fix. BTW, I found  `/Applications/Install Xcode.app` useful because I could copy it to another machine without another 3+ GB download.

Answer (score 6):

I still had this problem after installing Xcode, because Xcode didn't automatically install the "Command Line Tools for Xcode" package. This is available from Xcode | Preferences | Downloads | Components and click 'Install' next to 'Command Line Tools'.

Now that this is a separate package, it's also possible to solve this problem without installing all of Xcode (ie. you can just install this package :-)